# How to serve django static files via kong and nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, kong

I have Django app, nginx and Kongo. I configured the service and routes. I have a simple web page with a form. In order to display it correctly, you need to load static files such as js, css, png. I don't understand how to tell Kongo routes to static files.

django nginx kong deployed in docker. Didn't find any information on how to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.